# Trigger button click of react-bootstrap-multiselect on hover

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am trying to use [react-bootstrap-multiselect](https://github.com/skratchdot/react-bootstrap-multiselect), but I require it to trigger a button click on hover. Is there a way to do this using React.js?

I have looked through the source code and documentation but can not find what I am looking for.

Comment: you want to trigger button click on hovering a button?

Comment: Yes, the mutliselect component creates a drop down that is triggered by a button, I would like to see the drop drown when hovering over the object. I think I need to trigger a button click on hover but am unsure of how to accomplish it.